# Clojure.org documentation on compilation and gen-class

Tags: clojure, gen-class

1. I am reading the [documention](http://clojure.org/reference/compilation) on clojure.org about compilation, the last part gen-class examples. I do the examples and then when trying to run it as java app with: `java -cp ./classes:clojure.jar clojure.examples.hello Fred` in the terminal i get : `Error: Could not find or load main class clojure.examples.hello`. Can someone help?
2. Can someone introduce where to learn about gen-class and :gen-class, i find not much documentation on web

Comment: Do you have a classes directory in directory where you run the `java -cp` command? Try to find a file named clojure/examples/hello.class

Comment: I have generated some project **tst** with leiningen, and there is a classes directory in: **tst/target/base+system+user+dave**. So i `cd` to the directory **base+system+user+dave** and from there i run `java -cp ./classes:clojure.jar tst.core Fred` and i get: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: clojure/lang/IFn` Error, i try `java -cp ./classes:clojure.jar tst Fred` and i get `Error: Could not find or load main class tst`

Answer (score 4):

The command `java -cp ./classes:clojure.jar tst.core` from your base+system+user+dave is almost correct. The `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: clojure/lang/IFn` error is because the JVM cannot find the Clojure classes as there is no `clojure.jar` file in the `base+system+user+dave` directory, so you need to specify the correct path for the clojure.jar file.

As you are using `lein`, it downloads your project dependencies to your [local repository](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/where-is-maven-local-repository/). One of the dependencies will be Clojure itself, so assuming you are on iOS/Linux and that your lein project.clj has a dependency with clojure 1.7.0, the command to run from the base+system+user+dave directory will be:

```
java -cp ./classes:~/.m2/repository/org/clojure/clojure/1.7.0/clojure-1.7.0.jar tst.core
```

As this gets quite annoying once you have more than one dependency, I would suggest to use `lein uberjar` that will create a file in the `target` directory called your-project-name-standalone.jar that will have all required classes, so to run it from the command line go to the target directory and run something like :

```
java -cp tst-standalone.jar tst.core
```

To understand more about how the classpath works in the JVM, you can start with [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_(Java))

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, but non of them still work for me! I run `java -cp ./classes:~/.m2/repository/org/clojure/clojure/1.7.0/clojure-1.7.0.jar tst.core` from **base+system+user+dave** dir and get: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: clojure/lang/IFn`

Comment: You have to find the location of the Clojure jar being used on YOUR SYSTEM and plug it into the command.